# How to compare multiple fields across multiples tables, at scale?

Tags: python, sql, database

I have multiple tables T1, T2, ...Tn

I want to compare fields in T1, T2 etc, to see if fields with the same name have the same values.

E.g. 
**T1** 
column_a

**T2** 
column_a

So

```
SELECT a.column_a, b.column_a
FROM T1 
JOIN T2 
ON T1.column_a = T2.column_a
```

Pretty simple, but how can I do this at scale? Is there a way in Python to do this?

For example, using some pseudocode.

```
get column1 in T1
if column1 in T2, T3...Tn
compare values and get percentage match

get column2 in T2
if column2 in T2, T3...Tn
compare values and get percentage match
```

This is the output I'd like
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAuW8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can use `union all` and aggregate:

```
select num_t1, num_t2, num_t3, count(*),
       min(column_a), max(column_a)
from (select column_a, sum(t1) as num_t1, sum(t2) as num_t2, sum(t3) as num_t3
      from ((select column_a, 1 as t1, 0 as t2, 0 as t3
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select column_a, 0 as t1, 1 as t2, 0 as t3
             from table2
            ) union all
            (select column_a, 0 as t1, 0 as t2, 1 as t3
             from table3
            )
           ) t
     ) t
group by num_t1, num_t2, num_t3;
```

This compares the number of times that values appear in all three (or "n") tables.  You can use `max()` instead of `sum()` just to see if the value is present.